# Dataframe applying a formula to a column referencing other columns

Tags: python

I have a panda's dataframe object with A as index, B and C as columns, as follows:

If I want to add a new column, column D, that needs to apply a mathematical calculation based on column C on a rolling basis (eg, column d = square root of the average of the past 5 rows of column C). what is the best way to do that?

Thank you for all your patience and answering it.

Comment: Questions always work better when you include your code and sample data. Also, `A` and `B` are not used anywhere in your problem. Why mention them at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself, the best way is to use rolling calculation:

```
df['D'] = df.rolling(5)['C'].max()
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. But what if the rolling calculation that I want to apply is a mathematical formula other than the inbuilt max, eg say i wanna do a square root of 3 applied to the average of the past 5 rolls for each cell in column D?

Comment: Then you must update the question, in the first place.